How can i avoid boilerplate code with Astro.currentLocale?
Here is an example of how i am using the Astro.currentLocale for translations in Astro.
---
import { getRelativeLocaleUrl } from "astro:i18n"

// Components
// imports ...

// i18n
import { getTranslations, type Lang } from "@/i18n/utils"

const lang = Astro.currentLocale as Lang
const t = getTranslations(lang)
---

<div>
    <div>
        <h2>{t("any-title")}</h2>
        <div>
            <a href={getRelativeLocaleUrl(lang, "any/route")}>
                {t("view-details")}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <InventorySummaryLineChart lang={lang} client:load />
        <InventorySummaryBarChart lang={lang} client:load />
        <InventorySummaryPieChart lang={lang} client:load />
    </div>
</div>

In the last div tag, where i have 3 diferent charts i want them to be 'prerendered' so the title and description is already translated when it hits the client.
But i am being forced to pass the lang as a prop, because i can't use window to get the url with the lang, and the document.documentElement.lang neither cause the layout with the lang setted could be rendered later.
How can i avoid then pass the lang as a param to framework components? and be able to get it in server side?
Maybe with a state manager, but how can i avoid rehydration problems?

You can assign values in an Astro middleware to Astro.locals, but that you can only read out in Astro components, not framework components.
If you have a React framework component, you can use React context:
Astro part:
---
import { getTranslations } from "@/i18n/utils"

const lang = Astro.currentLocale
const t = getTranslations(lang)
---
<App client:load lang={lang} />

React part:
// LangContext.jsx
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const LangContext = createContext()

// App.jsx
import { LangContext } from './LangContext'

export const App = (props) =>
  <LangContext.Provider value={props.lang}>
    <InventorySummaryLineChart />
    <InventorySummaryBarChart />
    <InventorySummaryPieChart />
  </LangContext>

The various charts can now access the React context.
